# Github webpages not rendering

Tags: github, safari

I was perusing on Github when all of a sudden the layout went to this...

[image: Bad Github layout]

I tried it on both Safari and Firefox but both will not render the Github webpage correctly. I realize this is not so much a coding problem, but more of a web development problem...any help or suggestions would be great!

Comment: I assume this is your personal site.  I also assume you are using github pages.  Did you make any changes to your repository when this happened?

Comment: I actually was looking at someone else's repository, I clicked a link to their R code and then the website changed. Now EVERY page on github looks like this.

Comment: What's the website?

Comment: That's kind of concerning, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: when i copy and paste https://github.com, this is the page i see. I'm a complete novice when it comes to website errors, so I don't know what you mean by "errors in your console"?